# Mixed markers on the same Oxyplot line?

Tags: wpf, markers, oxyplot, lineseries

I have a plot where three lines are shown. Each line has a marker that identifies its type.
The user can choose a type of line and click on the plot to create those lines.
No problems this far.

The problem is that i need one of those lines to have two distinct types of markers, for example, the user can right click somewhere on the plot, which will open a context menu and choose one option that would create a point with a special marker for that line. The question is: is it possible to mix markers on the same LineSeries? If the answer is yes, how can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it qualifies as a data series, if it has different markers. I think you need to keep a line series showing the line and muliple line series showing the different markers. You then need to sync all the series when adding a point.